# Two dimensional arraylist java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm trying to save data from text file into Two dimensional arraylist. Here's my 2d array list

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> students = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

and here's my arraylist

```
private ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and here I'm trying to fill my list with data

```
        public void addStudent(String student){
            a.add(student);
        }
        public void addToList(){
                students.add(a); // 


                System.out.println("TEST1 " + students);

                a.clear();

                System.out.println("TEST2 " + students);
            }
```

Here's my reading method

```
public void read(){

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\SuperUser\\IdeaProjects\\Test\\src\\data.txt"));
            String line = "";
            int num = 0;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
                if(tokens.length == 2){
                    if(num != 0){
                        a.addToList();
                    }
                    num++;
                }else{
                    a.addStudent(tokens[0]);
                }
            }
           // a.addToList();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here's my output

```
TEST1 [[Antanas, Kazys, Petras, Sonata]]
TEST2 [[]]
TEST1 [[Jonas, Martynas, Arturas, Vacys, Robertas], [Jonas, Martynas, Arturas, Vacys, Robertas]]
TEST2 [[], []]
TEST1 [[Mykolas, Aldona, Asta, Viktoras, Arturas, Vytas], [Mykolas, Aldona, Asta, Viktoras, Arturas, Vytas], [Mykolas, Aldona, Asta, Viktoras, Arturas, Vytas]]
TEST2 [[], [], []]
```

So why after clearing my list `a.clear()` it affects my Two dimensional arraylist? And why I lose my data?

**EDIT**
to  Abbé Résina

```
Information 4
Antanas 1 6.95
Kazys 2 8.65
Petras 2 7.01
Sonata 3 9.13
Economy 5
Jonas 1 6.95
Martynas 3 9.13
Arturas 2 7.01
Vacys 2 8.65
Robertas 3 6.43
Robotics 6
Mykolas 1 6.95
Aldona 3 9.13
Asta 2 7.01
Viktoras 2 8.65
Arturas 5 8.32
Vytas 3 7.85
Literature 4
Jonas 1 6.95
Zigmas 3 9.13
Arturas 2 7.01
Simas 3 6.43
```

Comment: Can you provide the input file ? and your code is not complete: e.g. the variable  `a` used in the `read` method is not the one you declare as an `ArrayList<>()`...

Comment: That is because all my lists are in inner class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that you are adding the same `ArrayList` reference to your "`2D ArrayList`".

Maybe you could try making a copy of the `ArrayList` every time you want to add a new student.

Or you could declare a new ArrayList every time you want to add the new student.